# React how to get wrapped component's height in HOC?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, react-ref

Is there any way to get the wrapped component's DOM height?

I tried adding an ref but the console errors me `Function components cannot be given refs.`

And I set the [forward ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components), but it seems not the case.

```
export default function withInfiniteScroll(Component) {  
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, true);
    }
    onScroll = () => {
      // here
      console.log(
        'window.innerHeight', window.innerHeight,
        '\ndocument.body.offsetHeight', document.body.offsetHeight,
      );
    }
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

I want to log the height of `Component`, but these logs are meaningless, they are html-body's height instead of `Component`'s.

```
window.innerHeight 767 
document.body.offsetHeight 767
```

But when I in chrome console:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('home-container')[0].clientHeight)
> 1484
```

Which the `'home-container'` is a wrapped component:

```
withInfiniteScroll(HomeContainer);
```

Comment: *And I set the forward ref, but it seems not the case* - how do you set it? No, this is the case. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @estus Hi, In HOC I create the forward ref, but how can I use it inside my HOC? And I think this is the point.

Comment: As any other ref. I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapped component should either expose a ref to underlying DOM element with `forwardRef`:

```
function withInfiniteScroll(Component) {  
  return class extends React.Component {
    ref = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, true);
    }

    onScroll = () => {
      console.log(this.ref.current.clientHeight);
    }

    render() {
      return <Component ref={this.ref} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

const Foo = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref}>Foo</div>
));

const FooWithScroll = withInfiniteScroll(Foo);
```

Or wrapper component should add container DOM element:

```
function withInfiniteScroll(Component) {  
  return class extends React.Component {
    // ...same as above

    render() {
      return <div ref={this.ref}><Component {...this.props} /></div>
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. And I think the second solution will mash the style up, so needing better thought to use it. Also sorry for *I tried adding an ref but the console errors me*, because I set the 'home-container' to function component. Change it to class will work: `const innterDom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.innterComponentRef.current)`

Comment: You can accept custom container element with respective style/class as a prop if styling is a problem, like `<FooWithScroll container={<span/>}/>`. The use of `findDOMNode` is discouraged, also requires a component to be a class, not always possible. Child component should be aware that it needs to expose a ref. This is what `forwardRef` does in the example. If it's not always feasible or practical, use a container around wrapped component.